# Should we have a generic "how to ask" question?

Tags: discussion

We often get questions saying "How do I ask my boss...?" or "How do I tell my boss...?" [This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/193758/best-way-to-ask-for-about-hybrid-remote-work) in my mind sums up exactly how they should be answered 90% of the time.

Should we make a generic question like it? Obviously we would go into more details about how it's usually best to just ask the question, and that the way you ask it (without being rude) usually isn't going to make any difference to the answer.

Comment: I think the word you were looking for was "canonical" (not "generic")

Comment: And another one https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/194101/is-it-reasonable-to-request-working-remotely-from-ecuador

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for it, but I'm not against it.